# Exotic CSV Dialect Parsing

Tags: python-3.x, csv, parsing

I cannot seem to find the correct Python3 CSV reader args to use to parse this particular CSV Dialect. The behavior of the thing generating the CSV is as following:

Parser information:

- Quotation character: **"** (\x22)
- Field Delimiter: **^** (\x5e)
- Record Separator: **\n** (\x0a)
- Escape Character **\** (\x5c)

How the CSV which generated this format works:

- If the specified record separator is found in a field, quote field
- If the specified field separator is found in a field, quote the field.
- If the specified quotation character is found in a field, quote the field and escape the quotation character
- If the specified escape character is found in a field, do nothing...

^ this last point is what is causing me an issue since my first field of a particular row ends with a backslash. This causes the Python3 CSV parser to interpret the first field separator as being escaped.

See below:

```
(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/csv$ python --version
Python 3.6.4
(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/csv$ cat test_csv.py 
import csv
with open('exotic_dialect.csv') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='^', quotechar='"',
                    escapechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for row in reader:
    print(row)

(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/csv$ cat exotic_dialect.csv 
a^b^c
a|^b^c
"a\""^b^c
"a^"^b^c
a\^b^c
(xcve) ttucker@plato:~/tmp/csv$ python test_csv.py 
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a|', 'b', 'c']
['a"', 'b', 'c']
['a^', 'b', 'c']
['a^b', 'c']

^ This last list should have three fields; i.e., ['a\', 'b', 'c']
```

So, my questions are:

1. Can this CSV Dialect be parsed by the default Python Lib (but with some specific options I can't seem to find)
2. Can this be easily parsed by some python code (Also, assume that the first field ends in every printable ascii)

Comment: This will not work with the `csv` module as the `escapechar` is explicitly defined as escaping the `delimiter`. It can also escape the `quotechar` if `doublequote` is `False`. So there is no way to just escape the `quotechar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, doing string replaces on the data first wasn't the best idea because there wouldn't be any way to determine if unescaped-escape character should be escaped without understanding it's context. I ended up just writing my own parser.

```
class XcCsv(object):
    def __init__(self, field_delim, record_delim, quote_char, escape_char):
        self._field_delim = field_delim
        self._record_delim = record_delim
        self._quote_char = quote_char
        self._escape_char = escape_char

        self._records = []
        self._record_buf = []
        self._field_buf = ""
        self._in_quote = False
        self._in_escape = False

    # This could be different ...
    def _walker(self, data):
        data_length = len(data)
        if data_length == 1:
            self._parse_char(data)
        else:
            for d in data:
                self._walker(d)

    def _parse_char(self, char):
        if self._in_escape:
            self._field_buf += char
            self._in_escape = False
        elif char == self._escape_char:
            if self._in_quote:
                self._in_escape = True
            else:
                self._field_buf += char
        elif char == self._quote_char:
            if self._in_quote:
                if self._in_escape == True:
                    self._field_buf += char
                else:
                    self._in_quote = False
            else:
                self._in_quote = True
        elif char == self._field_delim:
            if self._in_quote:
                self._field_buf += char
            else:
                self._record_buf.append(self._field_buf)
                self._field_buf = ""
        elif char == self._record_delim:
            if self._in_quote:
                self._field_buf += char
            else:
                self._record_buf.append(self._field_buf)
                self._records.append(self._record_buf)
            self._record_buf = []
            self._field_buf = ""
        else:
            self._field_buf += char

    def reader(self, data):
        self._walker(data)
        for rec in self._records:
            print(rec)

csv = XcCsv("^","\n","'","\\")
data = open("exotic_dialect.csv").readlines()
csv.reader(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in the subject, but

1) probably not. You are expecting the same escape character to do 2 different things in this context, and it would be impossible to differentiate. These CSV parsers generally take care of escaping characters *first*.

How would a CSV parser determine the correct behavior for this example?

- `fo\^o^bar`

  - `["fo\","o","bar"]`
  - `["fo^o","bar"]`

2) I personally would run your CSV through some pre-processing, so that you can correctly parse your file (replace `\^` with `\\^`)

Comment: The correct behavior is the first example since the escape character should only apply if inside of quotation characters

Comment: you would need a parser that has settings that allow you to ignore certain characters to escape, which I don't think exists. Try pre-processing the file